# Single file upload with url link retrieving

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to upload single image - so far it works fine. The question is how can I upload single image and after that link this single file in response. For example i would like to upload image file and after upload display this **single** file as href on www site.
views.py:

```
def res_img(request):
    form=ImageForm(request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    context= {
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, 'im_form.html',context)
```

models.py:

```
class Cimage(models.Model):
    height_field=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field=models.IntegerField(default=0)    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='img',null=True,blank=True,width_field="width_field",height_field="height_field")
```

If you have any simpliest please let me know.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_absoulte_url()` to your Cimage Class.
`get_absolute_url()` is just method that returns object's url.

```
def res_img(request):
    form=ImageForm(request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    context= {
        "form":form,
        "url": instance.get_absolute_url()
    }
    return render(request, 'im_form.html',context)


class Cimage(models.Model):
    height_field=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='img',null=True,blank=True,width_field="width_field",height_field="height_field")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/img/%s' % self.image.name
```

Plus, i think `upload_to='img'` will makes problem. you can use `upload_to='img/'`

Comment: I did some small changes and it works well, thanks for help